# triple integral limits problem

Tags: real-analysis

$$\iiint_V\left(x^2+y^2\right)dx\,dy\,dz,$$ where $$V: z^2=\frac{h}{R}\left(x^2+y^2\right)\;\text{ and }\;z=h.$$ 
I don't know how to find the limits of the integrals.

Comment: If you don't show some work, this question will likely get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

V is an upside down cone with a circular base of radius $hR$ at $z=h$. So, you may integrate in cylindrical coordinates with the radial  limits $0\le r \le hR$ and the vertical limits $\sqrt{\frac hR} r\le z \le h$.